# How to stop application logs from logging into catalina.out in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

The application is running in `tomcat` and has it own logger using `org.apache.commons.logging.Log and org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.`
The logs are getting logged at location specified in `log4j.properties` file, the location is as follows.

```
log4j.appender.logger.File=${catalina.base}/logs/applicationlogs.log
```

The logs are simultaneously added in following file.

/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/logs/catalina.out

How to stop the application logs from getting logged in catalina.out ?

Answer (score 19):

You can try to do this:

1. Edit `"$CATALINA_BASE"/bin/catalina.sh` file
2. Find `CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out`
3. Replace with new path.

Don't forget to restart tomcat.

And as suggested in comments, to block writing to `catalina.out` entirely, set `CATALINA_OUT=/dev/null` in `catalina.sh`.

Comment: To stop writing to `catalina.out` entirely, set `CATALINA_OUT=/dev/null` in `catalina.sh`

Comment: I applied this solution in tomcat 9 and it threw an error when I called `startup.sh` so be careful

Answer (score 7):

I believe the recommended way to "augment" catalina.sh (catalina.bat on Windows) is to:

1. Create or update a script in ${CATALINA_BASE}/bin called
   **setenv.sh** (setenv.bat)
2. Add a line to set: ***CATALINA_OUT=/dev/null*** as noted above.
3. This script will be executed before executing catalina.sh/bat which will use any vars set. This is also the correct way to add to the CLASSPATH, add JAVA_OPTS, etc. without messing with catalina.sh/bat directly, which may be updated (overriden) with each tomcat upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

If your application is using a console appender, then those logs will go to catalina.out. You might want to check that in your application.
To disable logging to catalina.out, you can check discussion: [here](https://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/088ksm25k4/disabling-catalina-out-log)

Answer (score 3):

1. Find CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out in catalina.sh
   $CATALINA_BASE/bin
2. Set CATALINA_OUT=/dev/null
3. Restart Tomcat

You will see log file created as per your log configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using tomcat 7.0.50 and I've done following configuration.
To stop the application to log into catalina.out, you can do it by removing the handler. 
This can be achieved by editting `conf/logging.properties` and changing:

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

to

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Making the above changes does not work. I am using tomcat 8.0.26 and tried modifying  conf/logging.properties in different ways but the logging does not stop.

Comment: @rajb same with me, its very annoying

Answer (score 1):

You can try following to disable writing to `catalina.out` :

1. Locate and Edit File: {CATALINA_BASE}/bin/catalina.sh

Locate "**CATALINA_OUT**" and replace the path with "**/dev/null**":

`/dev/null` in Linux is a null device file. This will discard anything written to it.

```
 CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out // Original Location
 CATALINA_OUT=/dev/null // replace path to /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Just changing

```
CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out
```

To

```
CATALINA_OUT= /dev/null
```

In `catalina.sh` is not enough because the `CATALINA_OUT` variable will be used later in the script and that will cause an error to be thrown (aborting the startup).

What I've done instead was, I went to the command lines themselves and edited them so that the output itself will be redirected to `/dev/null`

(In Tomcat 9 it's in the `if` block in line ~447)

```
$_NOHUP "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
  -D$ENDORSED_PROP="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" \
  -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
  -Djava.security.manager \
  -Djava.security.policy=="\"$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.policy\"" \
  -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
  -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
  -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
  org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
  >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"
```

I've set the stdout stream to `/dev/null`

```
$_NOHUP "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
  -D$ENDORSED_PROP="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" \
  -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
  -Djava.security.manager \
  -Djava.security.policy=="\"$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.policy\"" \
  -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
  -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
  -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
  org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
  >> /dev/null 2>&1 "&"
```

[image]